# Cannot find upstart init script for Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, upstart

I installed Nginx. I can start, stop, etc... the service and the server are working on boot.

But, i cant seem to find the upstart init script for Nginx, not in /etc/init/ or anywhere in the system.

I read on the Nginx docs the following:

> If you install NGINX from a repository, then it is likely that you already have an init script installed. If you installed from source, then you’ll want to find a script from below to help you out.

They dont say where the init file is located in the case you installed Nginx using aptitude.

Can anyone tell me please?

UPDATE:

Linux version ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing nginx, you may see two extra packages installed:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
nginx nginx-common nginx-core
...
```

You may see all files installed by package:

```
dpkg -L nginx-common
...
/etc/init.d/nginx
...
```

It installs System V style init script, not upstart job.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the version of your OS.
In debian wheezy, the script is /etc/init.d/nginx

Comment: OK. I had seen it, but didnt gave that file the correct attention. I stills belongs to the old system V logic of startup, correct?